# Is this the right way to append an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning jQuery and lost about appending an image.  Is this the right way to append an image? It doesn't seem to be working.  I am also using latest version of Jquery.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<style>
.newlook {
    color: red;
    background-color: green !Important;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: Corbel;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    // $("p").css('color', 'blue');
    $('p').css({
        'color' : 'red',
        'background' : 'pink'
    })

    $('.the_cool').html("THE is cool");

    $('p.clicker').click(function() {
        $('p.clicker').html("Don't click here");
        $(this).css("color", "green");
    })
});
</script>
<p>Hello</p>
<span class="the_cool"></span>
<p class="clicker">Click here</p>

<ul>
    <li>.hide()</li>
    <li>.addClass()</li>
    <li>.toggle()</li>
    <li>.find()</li>
</ul>
    <p class="tryjquery">Try some more!</p>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.tryjquery').click(function() {

                // $("ul").hide();
                // $('.tryjquery').addClass("newlook");
                // $('ul').toggle();
                $('ul').find('li').addClass('newlook').toggle();
        })
    });
    </script>
    <h2>Click here</h2>
    <div class="here">Here</div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("h2").click(function() {
            $(this).append("<img src='https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2013/holiday-series-2013-2-5173241802915840-hp.png'>");
        })
    });
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to work here.. http://jsfiddle.net/RXbn5/ DId you try to debug/check the console to see what is going wrong.

Comment: And here http://jsfiddle.net/n9nn4/ make sure you reference jQuery

Comment: do you see any errors?

Comment: seems to be ok: http://jsfiddle.net/3b9x7/

Comment: I confirm - it works fine. Click on H1-element loads an image, as expected. You should see for error messages in Firebug or similar tool.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I tried to debug but no error.  I can't even get it to work via console.  even teh console message i tried to show doesn't work.  I am not sure what's going on.  Above is how i have it.

Comment: @ariel Uhmmm, you are missing the </script> tag at the end of the last script.

Comment: @CaptainKirk rookie mistake!

Comment: Didn't you say there were no errors in the console? That should definitely throw one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last script should be closed like this:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("h2").click(function() {
            $(this).append("<img src='https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2013/holiday-series-2013-2-5173241802915840-hp.png'>");
        })
    });
</script>
```